# convert a string containing a valid file path into a list of path components

Tags: python, path

Is there a function in python that takes as input variables with paths (a character containing a valid path) e.g.

```
["/Users/xyz/Dropbox/figures/foo.txt","/Users/xyz/Dropbox/figures/folder/"]
```

and converts them into a character vector of path components (e.g. directories).

e.g.

```
"/hello/world" -> ["hello", "world"]
"/hello/world/" -> ["hello", "world"]
```

or on windows

```
"a:\\hello\\world" -> ["a:", "hello", "world"]
```

Using this function I would like to implement for instance a similar functionality to this one of

```
find . -maxdepth 4
```

Comment: "and returns the depths of these paths in a platform-independent way?" - By "depth", you mean the number of path components from the filesystem root? What if a relative path is used? Anyway, it seems like you are asking two different things that are only vaguely, thematically related to each other (something to do with paths). What is the actual **problem you are trying to solve**?

Comment: `os.walk` to navigate the fs recursively, use `os.path` for platform independent manipulation

Comment: Your updated question searches levels 4 or less; is that really what you mean? Please [edit] to clarify (and probably remove the tangential second question at the end).

Answer (score 1):

The `-depth` predicate simply instructs `find` to traverse depth-first. I assume you mean `-mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4` which examines directory entries at depth 4 exactly.

The normal wildcard functions will work in Python just as in the shell.

```
import glob
level4 = glob.glob("*/*/*/*")
```

With `pathlib` you can say

```
from pathlib import Path
level4 = list(Path().glob("*/*/*/*"))
```

(The `Path.glob` method is a generator, so you need to wrap it in a `list` to traverse it immediately.)

We really only want one question per question, but for completeness' sake, finding the number of path components in a path name is fairly trivial; just count the number of `os.path.sep` but add one to the result if the path is relative; similarly subtract one if the last character is a separator.